# Unity Standard surface shader with tessellation

Tags: unity, shaders, tessellation

So I'm experimenting with tesselation to try and make a custom snowshader and after I finnaly manage to compile the shader without any errors.

The plane I'm using the shader on simply become completly invisible. Here is the entire shader code. I'm lost at what I'm doing wrong.

```
Shader "Custom/SnowTessellation" {
    Properties{
        _EdgeLength("Edge length", Range(2,50)) = 15
        _MainTex("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Glossiness("Glossiness", Range(0,1.0)) = 0
        _Metallic("Metallic", Range(0,1.0)) = 0
        _DispTex("Disp Texture", 2D) = "gray" {}
    _NormalMap("Normalmap", 2D) = "bump" {}
    _Displacement("Displacement", Range(0, 1.0)) = 0.3
        _Color("Color", color) = (1,1,1,0)
        _SpecColor("Spec color", color) = (0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5)
    }
        SubShader{
        Tags{ "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
        LOD 300

        CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows vertex:disp  tessellate:tessEdge nolightmap
#pragma target 5.0
#include "Tessellation.cginc"

        /*struct appdata {
        float4 vertex : POSITION;
        float4 tangent : TANGENT;
        float3 normal : NORMAL;
        float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
        float2 texcoord1 : TEXCOORD1;
        float2 texcoord2 : TEXCOORD2;
    };*/
        struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
    };
    float _EdgeLength;

    float4 tessEdge(appdata_full v0, appdata_full v1, appdata_full v2)
    {
        return UnityEdgeLengthBasedTess(v0.vertex, v1.vertex, v2.vertex, _EdgeLength);
    }

    sampler2D _DispTex;
    float _Displacement;

    void disp(inout appdata_full v)
    {
        UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(appdata_full, v);
        float d = tex2Dlod(_DispTex, float4(v.texcoord.xy,0,0)).a * _Displacement;
        v.vertex.xyz += v.normal * d;
    }



    sampler2D _MainTex;
    sampler2D _NormalMap;
    fixed4 _Color;
    half _Glossiness;
    half _Metallic;

    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
        // put per-instance properties here
        UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)


        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o) {
        fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        o.Metallic = _Metallic;
        o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        o.Normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D(_NormalMap, IN.uv_MainTex));
    }
    ENDCG
    }

    FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: try again by removing this line `UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(appdata_full, v);`

Comment: I think your Initialization Is wrong It should be something like this`void disp (inout appdata_full v, out Input o)
  {
  UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT(Input,o);`

Comment: Please check [SL-SurfaceShaderTessellation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaderTessellation.html).you don't need to use `UNITY_INITIALIZE_OUTPUT` In this shader.